# Custom Thumb Image for WPF Slider

Tags: vb.net, slider, visual-studio-2017

I am trying to set a custom image for the Thumb on a slider in a Visual Basic WPF application. All I could find was doing some shape and color customizing. I couldn't find out how to set a custom slider image. How would I take the image below and set it as the thumb image?

[image: Slider]

EDIT

I couldn't get that to work. I got a "Thumb" target type does not match type of element "Slider" with the code below. I'm not sure how to edit the properties of the "Thumb". I can't find anything online that contains some sort of Thumb code inside the 2  tags. If I set a Thumb style and try to apply it to the slider "Style" attribute, there is some sort of mismatch between the thumb style and the slider control. Can you customize the thumb of a slider all within a single  Tag?

```
<Slider Margin="902,104,105,384" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Orientation="Vertical" Minimum ="0" Maximum="255">
        <Slider.Style>
            <Style TargetType="Thumb">
                <Style.Setters>
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}">
                                <StackPanel Width="160"
                      Height="80"
                      Background="#FFFFFF"
                      Orientation="Horizontal">
                                    <Image Width="78"
                   Height="78"
                   Margin="0"
                   HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                   VerticalAlignment="Center"
                   Source="Images/TBar.png" />

                                </StackPanel>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style.Setters>
            </Style>
        </Slider.Style>    
    </Slider>
```

Comment: Are you changing the template in XAML or VB code.  You'll get a better answer if you show us code/xaml

Comment: I want to do it all in XAML if possible. All I want to do is create a slider with a custom image for the thumb. I'm not sure how these style settings work.

Answer (score 1):

Here's some XAML for changing the Thumb properties in a Style setter.

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="Thumb">

      <Style.Setters>
        <Setter Property="Template">
          <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}">
              <StackPanel Width="160"
                          Height="80"
                          Background="#00000000"
                          Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Image Width="78"
                       Height="78"
                       Margin="0"
                       HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                       VerticalAlignment="Center"
                       Source="eye.png" />

              </StackPanel>
            </ControlTemplate>
          </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
      </Style.Setters>
    </Style>

  </Window.Resources>
```

Comment: UWP has a different set of objects and types.  Ask a question and tag as UWP